# Is it possible to construct a type that allows objects but not Errors in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to fix a weird corner case in a logger, where calls like `log({ info: 'information' })` do work as expected, but `log(new Error())` does not.
While there's no fix avaiable, I want to override the log method to allow all objects but errors as parameters. Is it possible in Typescript?

I've tried with the new conditional types:

```
type NotError<T> = T extends Error ? never : T;

log(NotError<object>): void
```

But this still allows calls like `log(new Error())` without any errors or warnings.

PS: The bug is caused by all objects with properties that are not enumerable, but our only use case that envolves such objects are Errors.

Comment: Did you create this logger? If not what is it?

Comment: It's a extension of the winston logger: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

Comment: You don't need to override that stuff, check out their docs here on how to only log specific levels https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1108

Comment: The parameter inside log function is wrongly typed. Please see for reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gUQE5LkgPAFQHxQLxSZQQAewEAdgCYDOUyqSUA-FBRAG4RMBchA3AFgAUCIBmAVwoBjYAEs4FKABs4AcyzYAFDWBI+8Bmk0BKKAG8RUa1GmKacZRAB0qtTr0mhwgL4iRblrsAO70KGhaJl4B6lrmUACGfABECQBGyVA+XkA

Comment: It's a typing bug, not a log level bug. Winston typing allows calls like `Logger.error(new Error())` that won't work in any log level. I want to disallow this, while allowing `Logger.error({ myProp: `myValue`})`.

Comment: @r3dst0rm that works! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `NotError<object>` will just resolve to `object`. What you want is to use generics:

```
function log<T>(notError: NotError<T>): void {
  console.log(notError);
}
```

More reading: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this example](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1108)

```
const { createLogger, format } = require('winston');
const LEVEL = Symbol.for('level');

/**
 * Log only the messages the match `level`.
 */
function filterOnly(level) {
  return format(function (info) {
    if (info[LEVEL] === level) {
      return info;
    }
  })();
}

const logger = createLogger({
  format: zformat,
  transports: [
    // only 'info' level
    new transprts.File({
      level: 'info',
      format: filterOnly('info'),
      filename: 'logs/access.log',
    })name: 'logs/combined.log',
    })
  ]
});
```

and more docs on [filtering objects](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#filtering-info-objects)